# Does repeating (not reloading page) youtube videos consume bandwidth?

Tags: flash, networking, youtube, bandwidth

Does flash store youtube videos in the browser cache or get downloaded everytime you repeat the video ( not reloading the browser) by clicking the repeat button.

Also how about videos played in youtuberepeat.com? I am curious since I don't want to become a bandwidth offender at work.

I searched for results online and I couldn't find anything appropriate that would answer my question and hence resorting to the geeks at stackoverflow.

Edit:

argh.. I could have just switched off my wireless in my laptop when I am at home to find this... 
nevertheless would love to hear from you guys!

Edit:

I have tried loading a youtube video and youtuberepeat video, both of them works with my wireless switched off. looks like the browser's cache is storing this information.

Comment: You can't eliminate that this doesn't have to do anything with programming until you hear all the answers.. may be someone could explain this with a concept in flash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried loading a youtube video and youtuberepeat video, both of them works with my wireless switched off. looks like the browser's cache is storing this information.

Answer (score 0):

i think it does if you click replay. I always see the downloading bar showing as downloading. But if you move the progress bar ( i don't know the exact name) back it doesn't seems to be downloading again..